# Registering too many value converters in App.xaml.cs causes crash

Tags: wpf, debugging, exception, windows-phone, valueconverter

I add my value converters in the App.xaml.cs, but when I add one more it gives me an exception on application launch that I don't know how to handle. It is in the App.g.i.cs:

The exception:

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
        UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        };
#endif
```

Here are my converters in the App.xaml.cs

```
<Application x:Class="cMC.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="using:myApp">
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
     <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
       <ResourceDictionary Source="/Assets/ResourceDictionaries/ResrcDict1.xaml" />
       <ResourceDictionary Source="/DataTemplates/DataTemplates.xaml" />
     </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" xmlns:vm="using:myApp.ViewModel" />
        <ic:InverseBooleanConverter x:Key="InverseBoolToVisibility" xmlns:ic="using:myApp.Helpers"/>
        <mc:SegmentPartWrapper x:Key="SegmentPartWrapper" xmlns:mc="using:myApp.ViewModel"/>
        <mc:SegmentDateCNVRTR x:Key="SegmentDateCNVRTR" xmlns:mc="using:myApp.ViewModel"/>
        <mc:RailIconBooleanConverter x:Key="RailIconBooleanConverter" xmlns:mc="using:myApp.ViewModel"/>
        <mc:CarIconBooleanConverter x:Key="CarIconBooleanConverter" xmlns:mc="using:myApp.ViewModel"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

This one causes the problem "CarIconBooleanConverter", but its code in the ViewModel is the exact same as the "RailIconBooleanConverter"

```
<mc:CarIconBooleanConverter x:Key="CarIconBooleanConverter" xmlns:mc="using:myApp.ViewModel"/>
```

**EDIT:**

I removed one of the other converters from App.xaml.cs and "CarIconBooleanConverter" is working fine. Is it because there are too many converters?

Comment: Are you sure you get an exception because you register "too many converters"? If you remove another converter then add your `CarIconBooleanConverter`, does it work? Also, could you give the details of your exception?

Comment: KooKiz, I just commented one of the others and there is no problem.. Can it be because of the too many converters for real?

Comment: Can you please post the exception message? What you posted is not the exception - it's just the handler method ;) Also please post the code from your converters.

Comment: {System.InvalidOperationException: ServiceLocationProvider must be set.
   at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocator.get_Current()
   at myApp.App.<OnLaunched>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>b__3(Object state)
   at System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContext.Invoker.InvokeCore()} System.Exception {System.InvalidOperationException}

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that there is an issue with your MVVM Light class, ViewModelLocator. You may not have set it up properly. That or you haven't declared the default ServiceLocationProvider as is said in the exception.

```
    static ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
    }
```

See if that is in your ViewModelLocator class.

Comment: Also, if you believe that the issue is most certainly with your converters, try adding them into their own ResourceDictionary.xaml file in your app and just reference the converter dictionary as another MergedDictionary.

Comment: JamesCroft91, I added them to a separate Resource Dictionary, but the problem stands still

Comment: Have you checked your ViewModelLocator class however? It seems that the error you talked about above seems to be with the ServiceLocator.

Comment: I did and this piece of code is there. Actually I made a different project add many converters and its fine..